# Equivalence of or Difference between Pointer Expressions

Tags: c, pointers, translate, freepascal

I have a method which I want to translate **from c to pascal:**

```
void read28(uint32_t linearbuffer, uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t sectorcount) {

[...]

  uint32_t i;
  for(i = 0; i<sectorcount; i++) {
    insw(ATA_PRIMARY_DATA, (void *)target, 256);
    target += 256;
  }
}
```

insw is defined as `void insw(uint16_t port, void *addr, unsigned int count)`

Also I have the following ready method in pascal (which I could probably use for it):

```
Procedure ReadPortW (Port : Longint; Var Buf; Count: longint);
```

I've already checked insw and ReadPortW - **both are aquivalent**

The only difference is the second parameter: in insw it's a pointer; in ReadPortW it's a variable parameter (which is passed over as a pointer (with "call by reference")) (or please correct me if I'm wrong)

I also tried to translate it on myself. But I thought, before I write some bullshit that I wouldn't even recognize next day, let's ask for advice on this beautiful forum.

I searched for existing threads too, but they couldn't help me... (or do I ask wrong questions???)

So let's create a new one.

- First, I want to know how to translate this snippet to pascal **without changing or adding new helper functions**.
- Then I would like to have an explanation of the solution.
- And finally what's the difference between pointers, arrays and variable parameters in both c and pascal, so I can look up from the posts while solving other similar problems.

Maybe I'm sounding a bit too rude, but I've tried to eliminate this issue **since a whole year** :-(

But I already thank you for your advice because I know there must be a saver for me _,-+°*

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your "question" contains too many questions, and too unfocused. Please try to concentrate on one issue at a time, and post one question per question.

Comment: As for C, pointers, arrays, their relationship, and what happens if you do arithmetic using pointers, should be detailed in any decent beginners book, tutorial or class. I'm sorry, but this isn't a good place to ask such basic questions which requires us to write basically tutorials or book-chapters.